# order of MVC execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Just trying to learn MVC2/ .net 4.0 at the same time. I am just using the generic template VS comes with when you start with a "MVC 2 Web" project (ie, the account controller and home controllers are setup for you).

So my question is that the view is strongly typed again a model. The model looks like this:

```
[PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public class RegisterModel {
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ValidatePasswordLength]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("School")]
    public string School { get; set; }

}
```

then I guess I press "register" on my web page and it executes the following from my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
        return View(model);
    }
```

so a couple of questions.

1) The classes that are [] above the method name.. are they executed (i dont know what term to use here) first? For example the model has a `[ValidatePasswordLength]` above its property. Does that mean upon submitting a password that dosnt validate, it dosnt even hit the controller? Can I also put this logic in the controller?

2) Where is `ModelState` class coming from ?

I just kinda wanna know in a flow chart way on how everything is connected in MVC. It seems like its a big circle, and there is no starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes aren't executed so much as checked.

During modelbinding the view model will be scanned for attributes, the model binder gets a list of these attributes and can then change its behaviour (eg the [bind] attribute affects if the model binder will try and populate a given property) or call the class (eg Validation attributes).

To answer your questions specifically:

1)Validation can happen in two places, either before the action is called, ie when your action takes a view model, or explicitly in the action when you call TryValidateModel. Either way the action is called, it is up to you to check validity and handle the response accordingly within the action as you did in your action above.

2) ModelState comes from the ModelBinder.

The easiest way to see how MVC works is to download the source, debug and step through a request.